# NullReferenceException when I pass variables to another form C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

So I have the following situation; I want to send a couple of variables to another form. Here is some code:

```
// In Form1
Form3 f3 = new Form3();
f3.SetVariables(pieces);
// In Form3
string[] items;
void SetVariables(string[] array)
{
    items = array;
}
```

Now this **does** work but if I try to use:

```
items[x].Length
```

It throws a `NullReferenceException`, but if I use:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(items[x]);
```

(I am checking to see if `items[x]` has a value)
The above code works perfectly, with no errors. Is there a reason behind this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post complete (non)working code, including the methods you all and the data you have in pieces to give any clues about what might be wrong.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo Pieces contains all strings and no null items that I know of. SetVariables literally sets pieces to items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String.IsNullOrEmpty will check for the variable being null in the first place.  Calling `items[x].Length` when `items[x]` is null will fail because there is no object to call `.Length` on

Comment: Hmm, that was what I was thinking. Thanks!